# Read list of string from user in Microsoft botframework

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot

I'm working on a chatbot project. I had a requirement like the bot need to get skills of the customers. this is the class i'm using.

```
    [Serializable]
    public class ExperiencedDetailFormModel
    {
        [Prompt("Please enter your {&}")]
        public string EducationalQualification { get; set; }

        [Prompt("Please enter name of your {&}")]
        public string CurrentOrganization { get; set; }

        [Prompt("Please enter your {&}")]
        public string CurrentPositionInTheOrganization { get; set; }

        [Prompt("Please enter your {&}")]
        public List<string> Skills { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to read skills entered by the user to the Skills property.

Comment: You want the user to enter any list of string? or you want a dynamic list that is taken from the db?

Comment: @AnitaGeorge I want to get list of string from user. Not from db

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to have FormFlow continue to accept answers, populating a list.  When would it 'know' it is time to move to the next field?  I think you will need to split up the form into multiple dialogs.  Please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47037451/formflow-add-multiple-entities-using-recurring-questions

Comment: @EricDahlvang, thanks for the reply, it might work :)